# Deploying custom resource through DSC PullServer fails to extract the module

Tags: powershell-4.0

I've set up a DSC PullServer on Server 2008 R2 and I've run into an issue deploying a custom module. The module on the PullServer is in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\NTFSPermission, I've zipped everything using Windows Explorer (and 7-zip) and placed the zip in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\DscService\Modules\NTFSPermission_1.0.zip, I create a checksum using NEW-DSCChecksum for the zip file and I've got Import-DSCResource NTFSPermission in my node configuration. When I run the Invoke-CimMethod to push the config to a node it errors out with:

Invoke-CimMethod : Failed to extract the module from zip file 
C:\Windows\TEMP\\635291179507191263\NTFSPermission_1.0.zip downloaded by Download 
Manager WebDownloadManager.

The node logs a 4104 error in the event viewer reading:

This event indicates that failure happens when LCM is trying to get the configuration from pull server using download manager WebDownloadManager. ErrorId is 0x1. ErrorDetail is Failed to extract the module from zip file C:\Windows\TEMP\\635291179507191263\NTFSPermission_1.0.zip downloaded by Download Manager WebDownloadManager.

Has anyone else run into this? I'm not sure if there's a config file somewhere that is literally piping in an extra backslash and causing an invalid download/extraction path or if there is something wrong with the zipped module. If I move the module over manually the config will be pushed and apply successfully, which leads me to believe it's not the module.

Comment: I'm working around the issue by running a config that ensures the module's zip file is present and then extracting the archive to the correct location, pushing that config, then running the actual config that I want and pushing that one to the node. It's an ugly work around and will be a pain to manage at scale, so hopefully someone can help discover the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with extracting zip files created using .NET compression class in 4.5. The workaround is to use the shell method of compressing files. That is, send to compressed archive option in right-click context menu or using Shell COM object.

Comment: Has there been any update on this? We're currently hitting the same issues with System.IO.FileStream compression in our DSC build as well.

Comment: No. It may get fixed in WMF 5.0 which is currently in preview.

Answer (score 0):

I tested one of the modules from the DSC Resource Kit and it extracted with no problems on the desired node. I tracked the problem down to the psd file that the author created for their DSC-Resource. I updated the CLRVersion to require 4.0 and removed RequiredModules, RequiredAssemblies, ScriptsToProcess, TypesToProcess,FormatsToProcess and NestedModules (all were empty values anyway), pushed the config without the workaround and it downloaded and extracted the resource.